# Java Thread & Unix Process

Tags: java, unix

Will a java thread have a unique PID in UNIX environment? If I want to kill a specific thread of execution , is it possible to be done outside the program?

Comment: Java threads do not have unique PIDs. They run as one process, so the only PID is for the entire JVM.

Comment: It's like a difference between process and thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle includes `jvisualvm` in the JDK\bin directory.  You can use it to view threads running inside running JVM's.  However, I don't see any support for terminating a thread.

Comment: Thanks @AJNuefeld.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) they say `Most implementations of the Java virtual machine run as a single process. A Java application can create additional processes using a ProcessBuilder object.` The alternative would be spawn a process instead of a thread.